# Why Are Flickr Resized Images Larger in File Size?

Tags: flickr

I have a 1440x900px JPG that is 128KB. When I upload it to Flickr, it resizes to a couple of sensible web defaults but the Large (1024x640px) image is now 303KB. I'm outputting the original through Photoshop with the following settings:

- Medium compression (30%)
- Not progressive
- Is Optimized
- Color profile is not embedded
- All metadata is included (EXIF)

Is there a way to treat the original so that after it is uploaded to Flickr the resized images are not larger in file size (KB) vs the original?